# Sparse matrix as result of multiplying two non-sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I want to multiply two non-sparse matrices in python, say `X` and `Y`. As result, I'll get `Z = XY`, but I only need some of the entries of `Z`. What's the most efficient way to do this? I need to do this kind of multiplications a lot of times.

I tried looping over the indexes that I need and then calculating the respective inner product, but it's very slow doing it this way. Any suggestions?

Comment: The question is too broad.  How do you choose the entries?  Randomly? some value range?  specific row and/or columns?  What proportion of possible values do you want to keep (i.e. what's the sparsity of the result)?

Comment: I'm working on recommendations systems, so each entry `(i, j)` of the matrix represents a rating given by user `i` to item `j` (for example Netflix movies). The entries I want to keep are the entries in which a rating has been given. The proportion of known values is usually less than 10% of the matrix, which has size 1000*4000.